# Mergin Input app does not display initial value

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

**Background:**

At 3.28.2, I am having trouble creating a desired **Mergin Input** attribute form.  I will describe the setup here:

One of the input fields can only take on values of NULL or 0 to 9. For this, I set up the *QGIS > Layer Properties > Attributes Form* as shown below.  Please note the minimum value of zero.

[image]

When tested by editing the QGIS attribute table, the form works correctly.  Note that the displayed minimum value is zero, as expected.  So far, so good:

[image]

**Problem:**

When synchronized with **Mergin Input** the form does not display the default zero value.  Instead, a blank appears:

[image]

A workaround involves pressing the + key, followed by the - key, as shown the in the next two screenshots:

[image]
[image]

**Question:**

How to force **Mergin Input** to display zero as a default value, as it does in QGIS?

Note that it is possible to accomplish this by setting the QGIS Attributes Form > *Default value* to zero.  However, that is not acceptable here because NULL has to be the default value.

**Edit:**

Using the expression suggested by Dror Bogin, a zero now appears.  Unfortunately this also greys out the + and - buttons, so no other values can be entered.  In other words, it remains "stuck" at zero:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `0` as your default value at the bottom?

Comment: Please see the last sentence in the OP.

Comment: From your last line I am assuming you want the field to remain NULL unless some condition is met, and then it should start as 0. From what I can currently see, this might be an issue issue with input/mergin as that is actually a pretty simple action, you just add this expression in the default value place `if(condition,0,NULL)` and the value should remain NULL as long as the condition isn't met.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: I want the field to remain NULL unless a condition is met.  I had hoped your comment would solve the problem, but it adds its own problem.  Please see my edit to the OP.

Comment: Is the decision whether it should be NULL or 0 based on another field? In which case Dror Bogin's suggestion of the expression would work something like: `if("is_nest", 0, NULL)` where `"is_nest"` is a boolean field declaring the presence/absence of a nest. When `true`, the value will be set to 0, otherwise, NULL. *(Or is that what you already tried?)*

Comment: You are saying: "the input fields can only take on values of NULL or 0 to 9" but showing a first screenshot where "Allow NULL" is actually not ticked. Could you fix/test that also?
Next step: if not already, you should consider searching/opening an issue about that question (potential bug) on: https://github.com/MerginMaps/input/issues?